# IC out of oven after baking

Tags: heat, heat-protection

Is it ok to take out the ICs/components from oven immediately after baking hours? Or is there a standard cool down temperature before opening of the oven after baking?

Comment: Are you talking about reflow or a drying cycle?

Answer (score 2):

Usually there is a cool-down ramp that is specified by the specific JEDEC standard relating to the solder composition and the part recommendations (in the case of reflow). Most reflow ovens are designed to allow this ramp to be configured (i.e. -5C/second) and then follow that pattern, cooling down by no more than that amount in a given interval. For baking-out moisture from the package, the logic presumably remains the same.

This is intended to remove the possibility of thermal shocking the component or upsetting the solder characteristics by changing the temperature too fast (components are made of different materials, these different materials having different expansion coefficients). The old chemistry lab example of taking a hot Pyrex flask and setting it on the cool lab counter cracking it is an example of what the cool-down ramp intends to avoid.

So in short, if the oven does follow a cool-down ramp, you're good to go as soon as it finishes. If it doesn't ramp the samples down, I'd allow them to come down significantly in temperature naturally before removing them.

[JEDEC standard J-STD-020D](https://www.adestotech.com/wp-content/uploads/jstd020d-01.pdf), section 5.4 might be a good reference for further reading.

Comment: Thank you! Yes my oven doesn't have a cool-down ramp. When I've taken the time of the temp to cool down from 125 to atleast 50, it will take 1 hour. Now what i'm doing is to slightly open the oven door after bake to speed up the cooling process. I think this is ok right?

Comment: @Junnifer That sounds like it should be fine. As long as a lot of the temperature drop of the devices is done steadily, you should be okay.